# How to prevent adding same JSON object or model to collection multiple times?

Tags: backbone.js

I get JSON data via ajax, then want to add these data to collection. I want to add/update new/existing objects to collection. I did it in two ways. Both are not working, and I kind of know why they are not working. But there must be solution for that.
**1)**

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Book});
var library = new Library();
var bookJSON = {
  title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
  author: "Scheherazade"
}
var book1 = new Book(bookJSON);
var book2 = new Book(bookJSON);
library.add(book1, {merge: true});
library.add(book2, {merge: true});
```

**Result** library.length = 2
**2)**

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Book});
var library = new Library();
var book = {
  title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
  author: "Scheherazade"
}
library.add(book, {merge: true});
library.add(book, {merge: true});
```

**Result** library.length = 2

I do want to add/update same model/JSON object only once to collection.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json has no `id` value, so Backbone does not know that they are the same when you add it twice.

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Book});
var library = new Library();
var book = {
  id: 1,   // 'id' is the default idAttribute.
  title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
  author: "Scheherazade"
}
library.add(book, {merge: true});
library.add(book, {merge: true});
```

Or:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'title'  // might not be a good thing to use as an id, though.
});
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Book});
var library = new Library();
var book = {
  title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
  author: "Scheherazade"
}
library.add(book, {merge: true});
library.add(book, {merge: true});
```

Normally, you would not set the id on the client side, you would let the server assign an id when you first save the new model. But... the lack of an `id` is why you see two with your code.

Comment: Thanks, it's working well. Just in case, for my situation, I need more than one `idAttribute` attribute. For example, `id` and `type`. If you know easier backbone way to achieve that, it would be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be ok, are you using backbone.js 0.9.9 or a higher version?
the merge option was added on the 0.9.9 version.

Comment: I'm using Backbone.js 1.0.0